# virtual functions trouble

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have 2 classes: one basic and one derivative. Also have structure.

```
struct D;

class A {
  public:
    virtual D Multiply(D one, D two) {
        //realization 
        return result;
    }
    virtual D Pow(D one, D two) {
        result = this->Multiply(one,two); //#1
        return result;
    }
};

class B: public virtual A {
   public:
     virtual D Multiply (D one, D two){
           //realization 
     }
};
```

Function `Multiply` **have** realization in `class A`. So, this code is good?

```
  B* b = new B();
  b->Pow(one,two);  // #2
```

and which function `A::Multiply` or `B::Multiply` will called at `#2`? I think, that `this` at `#1` will point to A-part of B-object.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Probably nothing happened, because Multiply is private.

Comment: sorry, all functions are public, i miss this

Comment: and this `B->Pow()` call `A::Multiply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will call B::Multiply, this is basic OO principals.

Comment: ok, i know OO, but you can try this code and not to be so pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

this didn't provide B::Multiply implementation so you will get compilation error (Unresolved External )
if you write your implementation in B class the compiler will call B::Multiply

Comment: i have already tested this app and this is what i got Error error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "virtual int __thiscall B::Multiply(int,int)" (?Multiply@B@@EAEHHH@Z)

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the question had been edited. Your answer was correct when the question did not provide a definition of `B::Multiply`. I've made a trivial edit to your answer in order to be able to revert my downvote.